Temperature of thermal dissociation of carbon monoxide?
I was reading a paper about CO2 splitting, which mentions limitations of high temperature approach:

NTP even in the presence of solid catalysts is not able itself to
effectively promote the CO2 to C + O2 splitting (Eq. 1) but needs to
be integrated with other approaches. For example, in a microwave
plasma torch, where the temperatures could reach about 6500−7000 °C in
the center of the plasma, CO is still the main product of CO2
dissociation, with C being formed in a minor amount. Recent results
evidence that CO2 can be converted even in the presence of O2 in a
plasma reactor, but still being CO the main product of CO2
decomposition.

It got me thinking, how high temperature is actually required to break the carbon oxygen triple bond in CO? When the equilibrium of thermal dissociation is gonna get shifted toward the products?

CO has the strongest bond among diatomic molecules, so the temperature should also be highest.
